# UICollectionViewCell background image out of cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview

I am trying to use the background property of my collection view cell to display an image. The problem is :

If my image is not squared, to be sure that it is not deformed, I use the .ScaleToFill property, but when I run the picture overflow the cell frame.

[image: Note that the borderline is hide]

Is there a way to fix it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set clipToBounds = true

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I was just writing the same thing :) I up and mark as resolved

Answer (score 0):

Okay, never mind.

I just had to add the following line after the background view set.

```
cell.clipsToBounds = true
```